# CodeIgniter, Multiple url possibilities that direct to same method

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I just started learning codeigniter, and i noticed that. After writing my own routes like this

```
$route['index'] = "front/index";
$route['page/(:any)'] = "front/page/$1";
$route['section/(:any)'] = "front/section/$1";
```

Now i can visit the methods and controllers using the old routes and the new ones.

URLS now possible:

```
localhost/index
localhost/front/index
localhost/front/index.html
```

Too many urls directing to the same location, i was wondering if it were possible to have only 1 url per each method, restricting all others without using external code. From code igniter itself.

Also: this destroys my ability to use the uri class to get segments from the url.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just have your index page as your default controller's only (index) function, In your case just the

```
$route['default_controller'] = "front";
```

Then all other pages have other controllers with their corresponding URI names, then you dont need ANY routing except the default. I ususally end up with a handful controllers like `page.php`, `news.php`, `blog.php`, `products.php`, `admin.php` etcetera.